# Why my custom error message created in my trigger different from the one showing up in my lwc

Tags: trigger, lightning-web-components

```
Trigger PIITrigger on bhdata__PII_Fields__c(before insert){
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    bhdata__PII_Fields__c[] piiFields = Trigger.new; 

    String objApiName;
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap;


for(bhdata__PII_Fields__c p: piiFields){
    objApiName=p.bhdata__Object_API_Name__c;
     fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
     System.debug(fieldMap);
     if(fieldMap.get(p.Field_API_Name__c.toLowerCase()) == null){
         p.addError('Can not create record');
      }
    //  if (fieldMap.get()== p.bhdata__Field_API_Name__c) {
    //      insert p;

    //  }
    //  else {
    //      p.bhdata__Field_API_Name__c.addError('Cannot insert record');
    //  }
}
    // for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){


    // }



}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is being discarded by the custom component that was created to create those records. You'll need to search for that error message in your code base, you should find the offending component.

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail.If possible?

Comment: @mnoor01 Start with the Lightning App PIIInfo, and go through your component hierarchy and look at the JavaScript controllers and helpers. I don't know exactly where the error is, but I know this is not a standard error, so it must be custom code.